# JavaScript não segue no fluxo do algoritmo

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, html5

**Exemplo :**

```
$("#segundaFeira").change(function(){
        valorSegundaFeira = calcularJornadaDeTrabalho(this.value);
        var x = valorFinalJornadaTrabalho();
        alert(x);
});
```

Perceba que a variável global `valorSegundaFeira` é definida por uma função que retorna um valor. até ai tudo bem o problema que quando eu chamo `change` está printando o `alert(x)` primeiro para depois entrar na funcão `calcularJornadaDeTrabalho` e definir o valor de `valorSegundaFeira`. Não sei porque não está seguindo o algoritmo estruturado.

**Código HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{segundaFeira}" >
                option value="" selected="selected">--</option>
                <option th:each="horario : ${listaHorarioTrabalhoDiario}" th:value="${horario.id}"
                                            th:text="${horario.descricao}">horario</option>
</select>
```

**Função calcularJornadaDeTrabalho**

```
function calcularJornadaDeTrabalho(value){
        var **= 440;
        var **= 528;
        var **= 480;
        var **= 540;
        var **= 480;
        var **= 240;
        var **= 360;
        var valorTotal = 0;
        var **= 0;

        $.get(urlJornadaTrabalho, {idHorario: value}).done(function (horario) {
            **= horario.**; 
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            if (**== '**') {
                valorTotal = **;
            }
            alert("vlrTotal " + valorTotal);
        }).fail(function(xhr) {
            console.log("erro ao fazer ajax na urlJornadaTrabalho");
        });
        return valorTotal;
    }
```

Comment: Poderia por favor nos mostrar o HTML também?

Comment: Posta a calcularJornadaDeTrabalho() também.

Comment: ok só um momento

Comment: pronto já fiz as edições

Comment: você usa algum framework/library js sem ser o jquery ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não somente jquery

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto o AJAX calcularJornadaDeTrabalho é feito sempre que o evento `change` ocorre?

Comment: @flpms sim é feito toda vez que chamo o evento change mas percebi que   ele não está entrando no $.Get na primeira chamada é como se por baixo dos panos ele chama-se duas vezes fazendo q na primeira vez o valor seja 0

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta com algo que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta com a implementação básica do valorFinalJornadaTrabalho?

Comment: @flpms essa função ela só faz as somas das váriaveis globais ex : valorSegundaFeira + valorTercaFeira

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @flpms já responde o motivo de isso não funcionar, você está trabalhando com promises e antes de aguardar o retorno da requisição e a promise ser resolvida você já retorna a variaval que ainda está sem o valor do calculo.

Tenta a seguinte solução:

```js
$("#segundaFeira").change(function() {
  calcularJornadaDeTrabalho(this.value).done(function(varloRetornadoPromise) {
    valorSegundaFeira = varloRetornadoPromise;
    var x = valorFinalJornadaTrabalho();
    alert(x);
  }).fail(function(error) {
    console.dir(error);
  });

});

function calcularJornadaDeTrabalho(value) {
  var * *= 440;
  var * *= 528;
  var * *= 480;
  var * *= 540;
  var * *= 480;
  var * *= 240;
  var * *= 360;
  var valorTotal = 0;
  var * *= 0;

  return $.get(urlJornadaTrabalho, {
    idHorario: value
  }).done(function(horario) { * *= horario.* * ;
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }

    return valorTotal;
  }).fail(function(xhr) {
    return "erro ao fazer ajax na urlJornadaTrabalho";
  });

}
```

Recomendo um pouco de estudo sobre promises e suas implementações no javascript para que possa entender perfeitamente o fluxo do código acima.

Comment: Esqueci da abordagem da Promisses, fiquei tão focado em explicar o motivo que esqueci dessa mão na roda.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está na parte assíncrona do Javascript.

Quando ocorre o evento `change` a função `calcularJornadaDeTrabalho` não completou a execução. Então a variável `valorSegundaFeira` está `undefined`.

Sugestão é que você corrija a execução de escopo global e no callback do evento `change` você chame a ação que preencha a variável `valorSegundaFeira` com a informação que você deseja.

Você pode passar a função `valorFinalJornadaTrabalho` como callback, no final da chamada da `calcularJornadaDeTrabalho`. A chamada ficaria assim:

```
calcularJornadaDeTrabalho(value, valorFinalJornadaTrabalho) {
    //Após o sucesso do AJAX
    valorFinalJornadaTrabalho(valores);
}
```

O `Javascript` é diferente das outras linguagens, ele não tem uma execução passo a passo, ele pode executar um AJAX enquanto você nem tem a resposta ainda executar a soma dos valores. Então para garantir a execução passo a passo você usa o callback, a ação que deve ser chamada após o termino da execução anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Sua chamada GET está rodando sincronicamente e até ter seu resultado as funções subsequentes já foram executadas.

Sugiro que utilize a chamada GET da seguinte maneira (async false):

```
$.ajax({
    url : urlJornadaTrabalho,
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    data: {idHorario: value},
    success : function(horario) {
        * *= horario.* * ;
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }
    if ( * *= = '**') {
      valorTotal = * * ;
    }

    return valorTotal;
    },
    error: function() {
       return "erro ao fazer ajax na urlJornadaTrabalho";
    }
 });
```

Comment: Eu não recomendaria essa abordagem @Iago. Você bloqueia qualquer outra ação do usuário durante a request. As abordagens com promises ou usando o callback no geral são melhores, por não causar o bloqueio.